# Filter specific child nodes along with the parent

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, parent-child, xslt-1.0

I need to retrieve the parent nodes along with only those child nodes matching specific attribute values. The input XML is

```
<ErrorList>
    <Table name="Table1" type="A">
        <Error category="Minor">
            <errorCode>100</errorCode>
            <errorMessage>msg-100</errorMessage>
        </Error>
        <Error category="Major">
            <errorCode>101</errorCode>
            <errorMessage>msg-101</errorMessage>
        </Error>
    </Table>
    <Table name="Table2" type="B">
        <Error category="Fatal">
            <errorCode>102</errorCode>
            <errorMessage>msg-102</errorMessage>
        </Error>
        <Error category="Major">
            <errorCode>105</errorCode>
            <errorMessage>msg-101</errorMessage>
        </Error>    
    </Table>
</ErrorList>
```

The XSL code below retrieves the Error nodes having category attribute Fatal or Minor:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Error[@category = 'Fatal'] | Error[@category = 'Minor']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I get:

```
<Error category="Minor">
        <errorCode>100</errorCode>
        <errorMessage>msg-100</errorMessage>
    </Error><Error category="Fatal">
        <errorCode>102</errorCode>
        <errorMessage>msg-102</errorMessage>
    </Error>
```

The expected output is below (need to retrieve the parent table node for the select child nodes):

```
   <Table name="Table1" type="A">
        <Error category="Minor">
            <errorCode>100</errorCode>
            <errorMessage>msg-100</errorMessage>
        </Error>
    </Table>
    <Table name="Table2" type="B">
        <Error category="Fatal">
            <errorCode>102</errorCode>
            <errorMessage>msg-102</errorMessage>
        </Error>
    </Table>
```

Can you please help me with the xsl to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a stylesheet that produces the desired result:

```
<xsl:template match="Error[@category = 'Fatal'] | Error[@category = 'Minor']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Table">
    <Table>
        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="@type"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Comment: Was there a reason you reconstituted the nodes in the result rather than use `<xsl:copy-of select="@name"/>` and `<xsl:copy-of select="@type"/>`?  Or `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` for the error elements?